# Slow to open a "Dynamic web project" fold in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I just met a problem that when I started the eclipse and opened a "Dynamic web project" folder in Eclipse Indigo, it took nearly 30 seconds to finish it. That was too slow.

There is only one project with several files (less than 10) in the project explorer. Btw, it works fine in the Navigator view.

I'm using a Macbook air 501 with only 2GB RAM, so I'm wandering if the RAM is enough or not. Or is there some configs should I do?

I'm also wandering how trace this problem. Is some kind of log there?

Comment: Try closing and reopening the project (*not* eclipse itself) - there may be some first-initialization costs involved.  If starting eclipse took that long... what do you expect, it has to spool up a **lot** of classes...

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. @X-Zero

Comment: It's not an error, so tracing won't do much good.  Are you on the latest release?  Are you giving the Eclipse process enough memory?

Comment: I am seeing the same slowness when opening files. I have set Xms/Xmx both to 1024m

Comment: @Lynn, No it didn't work. Indigo is pretty much unusable in its current state on my Mac Book Pro. Others have reported the same experience. I had to go back to use Helios, which works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try increasing the memory allocation to run eclipse by modifying eclipse.ini under eclipse's folder:

[image]

I used to need to increase up to 700MB to get the maximum performance.